# Touchpad stops working after a while in Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Whenever I use my touchpad and don't have my mouse with me, it stops working after about 10 - 15 minutes. If I try to move it it hangs a lot and moves a few pixels, really slow. TouchpadOff is set to 2 and whenever I set it to 0 with synclient TouchpadOff=0 it stays at 0 until I try to move the mouse with the touchpad and then goes back to 2.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me to bring it back.

In terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

As far as I can tell, xorg kills the touchbad ([see DebuggingTouchpadDetection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)) because it is buggy. Still investigating how to avoid this from happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I kind of gave up on this but I'll try it next time I don't have my mouse available.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.